# Angular - Download file from http get

Tags: angular, file, http, download, get

My Java Rest API has the below method:

```
@Path("file")

...

private static final String TEMP_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

@GET
@Path("{key}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getXml(@PathParam("key") String key) throws Exception {
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_").format(new Date()) + key + ".xml";
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(TEMP_PATH + fileName, "UTF-8");
    writer.println(getXML(key));
    writer.close();

    Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(new File(TEMP_PATH + fileName));
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

And my client request the file

```
const path = 'localhost:8080/server/api/file/' + '1';
this.http.get(path);
```

If I access the url from my browser, that request the file from http get, I can download it. But this don't works on my angular app.

Comment: try this window.open(path);

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen, precisely, and what happens instead? Note that you must subscribe to an observable, otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: I expect that the browser open a window to download the file, like happen when I use the same path in search bar. But nothing happens.

Comment: That won't happen. You're sending an AJAX request, so it's up to your JS code to handle the response. The browser won't open a dialog box. Use a simple link to the URL rather than sending an AJAX request.

Comment: I can't access the url because at production ambient the api is protected for an A. A. framework.